# Algorithm - How to reduce the complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, factorial, fifo

I'm currently facing an algorithmic problem were I could need some hints from you.

Here the problems details:
Given are n numbers of FIFOs with a capacity of k. There are also sixteen different elements. Now we fill those FIFOs with a random amount of different 
random elements. The task is to remove a given random amount of random elements from the FIFOs. It is possible that there is no optimal solution caused by other blocking elements (rotating the FIFO isn't allowed).
The best solution is the one which removes all or most elements (so there are more possible solutions).

Well here is an visualized example of three FIFOs (seperated by | ) and three elements (a, b and c):

```
   1 | 2 | 3  
  ---+---+---  
   . | b | c          <- last elements 
   . | b | a  
   a | a | b          <- first elements
```

I hope you now know what problem I'm facing. (please feel free to ask if there is anything unintelligible)

Here is my idea of an algorithm:

- Treat each FIFO seperately and check on how much elements possibly could get removed. (This step is necessary to remove the problems size in the following step)
- Try each possible combination to remove the elements. 
  Stop if there is a perfect combination which removes each element else remember the best combination (which is the one that removes the most elements).

So the worst case has a complexity of O(n^k) which is obviously horrible! I'd really appreciate any idea to reduce the complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. If you want to remove some number of elements, why not just start with the first FIFO and remove stuff until it's empty or you've removed the right number, then if necessary move on to the second, third, etc...

Comment: If you're trying to select a group of FIFOs so that the total number of elements they contain is equal to a given number. (if you want to remove either all or none of the elements from each FIFO), then this is equivalent to the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). It's np-complete, but the wiki page discusses a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "blocking elements." If you're trying to remove a given number of elements and they have to be distinct, then this is a different problem entirely.

Comment: You could see this problem as a storage system and you have the task to remove a list of item (our given elements). Let's take the example above: If I had to remove a list of elements (a,b,b) I couldn't take "a" of the first FIFO because I wouldn't be able to remove both "b" elements.anymore of the second FIFO and this is obviously the only solution for this set of elements.

Comment: I agree with other commenters that the problem is still ambiguously specified. Please clarify "The task is to remove a given random amount of random elements from the FIFOs" Such a statement could simply mean "Remove k elements at random." It could also mean "Remove k elements, i of type A, j of type B where (i+j=k)" It could also mean "Here is a random list of elements L = {...}. Remove the elements of L from the FIFOs *in that order*" or, it could be "Here is a random list of elements L = {...}. Remove the elements of L from the FIFOs *and order doesn't matter*""